# Trying to write an IF ( Match ); possible syntax error?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Highly likely this is a syntax error, but it's not throwing any errors.

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(MID(Z2,28,6),$AF$1:$AG1,0)),"Mismatch","Included")
```

I have Z2, Z2 contains the following text:

"Revenue account for invoice P13930."

Or something like that, so the Mid function is suppoused to match that code, P13930, and not if it is within the specified cells (Here, AF1 and AG1)

I tried copying the whole text, or even just the code to AF1 and AG1, but it never writes a match. What's wrong with it?

Based it on my prototype:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH($AE1,$AF1:$AG$1,0)),"Mismatch","Included")
```

Which does happen to work.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, I was wondering how to include the following scenarios:

Sometimes the code would look like this: P13930. and other times like this: P13930A. I'm not sure how to consider these as my knowledge is limited to Mid , Left , and Right. And as Jordan Mentioned, MATCH would be out of the picture given these variations.

Comment: `MATCH` will only match entire cell contents

Comment: Oh, ummm.. well I should have the whole case from the Mid trimming? To test, I simply copied the data to the other cells... (Also, if not match, what should I be looking at?)

Comment: If you evaluate your formula you will see that your mid function is also pulling a trailing space at the beginning, so you are searching for `" P13930"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If AF1 and AG1 contain codes like P13930A, you can use a wild card to match them like this

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(MID(Z2,29,6)&"*",$AF$1:$AG1,0)),"Mismatch","Included")
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please specify your question:
First which we can advice, is to correct mid function argument: 
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(MID(Z2,**29**,6),$AF$1:$AG1,0)),"Mismatch","Included")
MID(Z2,**29**,6) - will give you result P13930
and then you want to find this code in some area, don't you? for example in the area AF1:AG1.

Please specify the result which you want to see in the cell AF2:
(a) code P13930; (b) INCLUDED - if area AF1:AG1 includes code P13930; (c) MISMATCHED - if area AF1:AG1 does NOT include code P13930 and etc.

Comment: Both C and B actually, I did something similar with my formula, but I wasn't sure how to include the edge cases when an extra letter is involved, as per my edit. Yes, I have 2 columns basically. one that will say Match or mismatch, with the formula, and then column b with the sentence.

Comment: As I see you have already received and marked correct answer to your question. I think that my formula also gives the correct result, does not it?

Comment: It does, but the wildcard suggestion was certainly helpful and it answered my followup Edit succinctly.

Comment: Great! Question is yours and it's up to you to mark the most accurate answer.